# Php - cannot create new database record because primary key is null (autoincrement)

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

There are two tables: address and person. person_id (primary key, autoincrement) is a foreign key to address. I am trying to add an address record and person record from the same form but am getting this error.

> Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "person_id" on null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\Main.php:22 Stack trace: #0 [internal
> function]: app\controllers\Main->insert() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\core\App.php(52): call_user_func_array(Array,
> Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(4): app\core\App->__construct() #3
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\Main.php on line 22

```
    public function insert(){
        if(isset($_POST['action'])){
            $person = new \app\models\Person();
            $person->first_name =($_POST['first_name']);
            $person->last_name =($_POST['last_name']);
            $person->notes =($_POST['notes']);
            $person->insert();

            $address->person_id = $person->person_id; //this is line 22
            $address->description =($_POST['description']);
            $address->street_address =($_POST['street_address']);
            $address->city =($_POST['city']);
            $address->province =($_POST['province']);
            $address->zip_code =($_POST['zip_code']);
            $address->country_code =($_POST['country_code']);
            $address->insert();         
            header('location:/Main/index');
        }else
            $this->view('Main/insert');
    }
```

Person insert method

```
    public function insert(){
        $SQL = 'INSERT INTO Person(person_id, first_name, last_name, `notes`) VALUES (:person_id,:first_name, :last_name, :notes)';
        $STMT = self::$_connection->prepare($SQL);
        $STMT->execute(['person_id'=>$this->person_id, 'first_name'=>$this->first_name, 'last_name'=>$this->last_name,'notes'=>$this->notes]);
    }
```

Address insert

```
    public function insert(){
        $SQL = 'INSERT INTO Address(person_id, description, street_address, city, province, zip_code, country_code) VALUES (:person_id, :description, :street_address, :city, :province, :zip_code, :country_code)';
        $STMT = self::$_connection->prepare($SQL);
        $STMT->execute(['person_id'=>$this->person_id, 'description'=>$this->description, 'street_address'=>$this->street_address, 'city'=>$this->city, 'province'=>$this->province, 'zip_code'=>$this->zip_code, 'country_code'=>$this->country_code]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you check if the person record is inserted to the database ?

Comment: yes the person record is added into the database with an auto generated person_id but the address record is not.

Comment: `$address->person_id = ...` - so where is `$address` supposed to come from in that position then? You did not create it inside the method, it was not passed in as a parameter, and you did not import it from the global scope either.

Comment: @JessicaAlmany, you need to get the last inserted id of the first insert before the second insert. Because the execute command  will return only boolean ie true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `mysqli insert_id`, after executing the insert command. `insert_id` will give you the primary key of the insert.

After

```
$person->insert();
$address->person_id = $person->insert_id;
```

Comment: I can't do this using pdo. My connection is in another file.

Comment: (new error) Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'person_id' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Address.php:37 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Address.php(37): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\Main.php(30): app\models\Address->insert() #2 [internal function]: app\controllers\Main->insert() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\core\App.php(52): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(4): app\core\App->__construct() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Address.php on line 37

Answer (score 0):

At no time do you use your `Address` model to insert the data into your **address** table.

Modify your code by adding this line :

```
$address = new \app\models\Address(); //ADD THIS LINE
$address->person_id = $person->person_id;
//...
```